# What's this PHP snippet doing?

Tags: php

```
$from = 'no-reply@'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Especially what's `ENT_COMPAT` for?

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars` encodes all characters than can be encoded as entities. This is especially important for angle brackets and ampersands. `ENT_COMPAT` will leave single quotes in place and only convert double quotes. `'UTF-8'` will treat the input as UTF-8 encoded (instead of the default iso-latin1 encoding).

In this case, the `htmlspecialchars` makes only sense if the mail address will be put into a `"mailto:" href` attribute. Normal server names don't have characters that must be encoded, so I'm not sure if `htmlspecialchars` is needed.

Comment: i doubt such an address can be used in the "mailto:" href attribute :)

Comment: Has anyone tested what's the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in case of internationalized domain names? This is the only instance where escaping could make sense

Answer (score 0):

forming a email address, quite stupid way

For the answer to the question `Especially what's ENT_COMPAT for?` you can browse PHP documentation for the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), because it's this function's parameter

Answer (score 0):

Creating a valid looking email semi-auotmatic. The email username is 'no-reply' and the domain is whatever the servers hostname is. With a 'no-reply' the recipient usually does not reply to these emails.

ENT_COMPAT is explained here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php